# junit test case about @override method

Tags: java, junit4

I am working on the Junit test case and the grading scheme is based on the coverage of the code.
I meet a problem about some @override method inside a method because it seems like I can not call that method.
Just like the example below.

```
public void showFollowersList(PagableResponseList<User> followers) {
  m_itemList.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
  @Override
  public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
    m_itemList.setLayoutData(new RowData(m_itemList.getBounds().width, 
                                         m_itemList.getBounds().height));
    m_rightFrame.layout();
    m_rightFrame.pack();
  }
});
}

addMouseTrackListener(new MouseTrackListener() {
  @Override
  public void mouseHover(MouseEvent arg0) {
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseExit(MouseEvent arg0) {
    Rectangle rect = HoverClickableComposite.this.getClientArea();
    if (!m_clicked && !rect.contains(arg0.x, arg0.y)) {
      setBackground(m_origColor);
    }
  }
```

How can I call or cover the method like handleEvent , mouseExit and mouseHover ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps, I think someone's done a very good job at making `showFollowersList` un-testable. Was that deliberate?

If so, the correct answer might not actually be a set of test code, but a very low coverage score and a list of recommendations for changing the class to make it more testable...

The only way to test it at the moment would be to set things up, poke it, and check what happens.
And that would only work if you can cause a `handleEvent` call to be fired on your object, and certain methods were available on the class:`getList`, `getListenerCount`, etc. Then, something like:

```
testObject.showFollowersList(followers);
// All that method does is add listener. So check that listener got added
assertEquals(1, testObject.getList().getListenerCount());

// Now check that inner handlers behave correctly
testObject.getList().fireEvent();
// This should have created a new RowData in the list
assertNotNull(testObject.getList().getLayoutData());
```

But if you **don't** have those methods available, then it's definitely not a good idea to add them and expose the `List` just for the sake of Unit Testing.

Another problem is the GUI. Your Unit Tests won't have a GUI. So, your `m_rightFrame` will probably be null (and even if it isn't, the underlying AWT classes will be).

Answer (score 0):

It is not a method 'inside a method', it is a method of an anonymous class.

Usually, with SWT or Swing programming, it is the functional (business) aspect of the code that requires much test coverage, and not the scaffolding (handlers etc.)

However, if this is what is required, there are at least two options -

1. Do not use anonymous inner classes for the handlers - give them names in the same package.
2. Use a mocking framework like Powermock with JUnit and pass mocked SWT event objects to invoke handlers so that you have coverage.